Why is my assembly code giving extra output?
Before I start, it's important to say I am a complete beginner to Assembly, so I might be missing something very obvious.
I was trying to make an Assembly program where it prints the following output in the Linux terminal:
Loading.
Loading..
Loading...

(with a one second pause between each)
So I started my project and wrote the code below (bear in mind I didn't even try to add the pause yet, just trying to print one variable to check I haven't used a wrong register or something).
global _start

section .text
_start:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, msg1
        mov rdx, msglen1
        syscall

        mov rax, 60
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall
section .data
        msg1 db "Loading.",0xa
        msg2 db "Loading..",0xa
        msg3 db "Loading...",0xa
        msglen1 equ $-msg1
        msglen2 equ $-msg2
        msglen3 equ $-msg3

Then, I ran the usual commands I use to compile it:
nasm -f elf64 -o Pause.o Pause.asm
ld -o Pause Pause.o

Yet, when I run the program using ./Pause, I get the output of:
Loading.
Loading..
Loading...

I have only told it to print msg1 so far, but it appears to have 'dumped' all the variables out.
How is this even possible and, more importantly, what have I done wrong?

msglen1 is the length of all three messages together.  msglen2 is the length of messages 2 and 3.  Only msglen3 has the value you intended, because that's the only one where you computed the length at a point where the length is knowable.

How? I thought using $- assigns it to the length of the variable, no?

Your messages should be declared msg1 db "Loading.",0xa\n msglen1 equ $-msg1\n msg2 db "Loading..",0xa\n msglen2 equ $-msg2\n msg3 db "Loading...",0xa\n msglen3 equ $-msg3 (where the \ns are actual new lines).

$-msg1 is just math - the current location, minus the indicated label.  Since you performed this calculation after all three messages had been defined, it's producing the total length of all three messages.  You either need to put the length calculation immediately after the message, or use something like msglen1 equ msg2-msg1.

$ is used as a shortcut so you don't have to declare a msgX_end label for each string. In exchange it only works right at the end of the string whose length you want to calculate because that's when $ is at the end of that particular string.
